# Apache redirect images based on referer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-referer

I'd like to redirect an image to another if the visit comes from certain traffic source. I have a link of a campaign like
https://domain.tracker.com/test/campaign/.

In my .htaccess file I've set something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain.tracker.com
RewriteRule /image.png http://www.example.com/image2.png [R=301,L,NC]
```

but when I test the campaign there's no redirect.

If I delete RewriteCond, the redirect is performed correctly, so I guess there's something wrong with the rewrite condition. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain.tracker.com [NC]
RewriteRule image\.png http://www.example.com/image2.png [R=301,L,NC]
```

There is no `/` at the beginning of the RewriteRule test (in .htaccess)

Comment: I fixed it but still same problem. If I put no rewrite condition, every visitor see image2 and that's ok. If I introduce the rewrite condition, I see the first image, even if I come from campaign link (domain.tracker.com/etc). Maybe there are some problems in recognizing the tracker domain?

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try from other browser ?

Comment: Yep, sure. I double-checked with Chrome incognito mode and from a friend's computer.

Comment: Sure, you're right! In any case even with other browser I still see no redirect.